# Selenium server is not starting for easyb project

Tags: java, ubuntu, selenium, easyb

[FAILURE: Could not contact Selenium Server; have you started it on 'localhost:4444' ? Read more at http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/not-started.html Connection refused]

Hi..
I am working on easyB and encounters the above problem
how can start the selenium rc server and what this problem is all about?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could write a groovy script into [your-webapp]/scripts/**_Events.groovy** to start and stop selenium
(You would have to install selenium-rc plugin before to have access to the seleniumConfig or selenium Server scripts. )

```
   includeTargets << new File("$seleniumRcPluginDir/scripts/_SeleniumConfig.groovy")
includeTargets << new File("$seleniumRcPluginDir/scripts/_SeleniumServer.groovy")

eventTestPhaseStart = { phase ->
    if(isAcceptance(phase)){
      startSeleniumServer()
    }
}
eventTestPhaseEnd = { phase ->
    if(isAcceptance(phase)){
      stopSeleniumServer()
    }
}
isAcceptance = { phase->
     phase?.contains("acceptance");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the Selenium Server first before you can use the client instance.
So before you call your defaultSelenium instance creation, you can start your server by using a RemoteControlConfiguration ([Link to javadoc](http://jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-rc-documentation/1.0/selenium-rc-documentation-1.0-doc.zip!/server/org/openqa/selenium/server/RemoteControlConfiguration.html)) object and use it as an argument for the SeleniumServer constructor call and then boot the server using the serverinstance.boot() call.

Something like

```
RemoteControlConfiguration rcc = new RemoteControlConfiguration()
//set whatever values you want your rc to start with:port,logoutfile,profile etc.

SeleniumServer ss = new SeleniumServer(rcc)
ss.boot()
```

Make sure you shut it down when you are done with tests.